# Best way to replace nested loop concatenate string using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of `names` and a list of `versions`. I want to get all permutations which are constructed by concatenating the string from two lists. I am using two for loop to do this but I want to switch to a more functional style approach. Here is my solution:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> versions = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
names.forEach(name -> versions.stream().map(version -> result.add(name.concat(version))));
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This code doesn't do anything, what result did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the "Cartesian Product" of `names` and `versions` — basically the return set/list from the aforementioned sets/lists.

```java
final Stream<List<String>> result = names.stream()
    .flatMap(s1 -> versions.stream().flatMap(s2 -> Stream.of(Arrays.asList(s1, s2))));
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> Keep in mind that operation is super expensive. Google's Guava have this implemented also under `com.google.common.collect.Sets.cartesianProduct(s1, s2)`.

Comment: can you update why it's more expensive than the traditional two for loop approach?

Comment: You can benchmark both "experiments" to come to a conclusion. However the performance with Java streams is (almost) always worse than traditional loops, but not significant enough to replace them all. In my experience, performance have been rarely an issue; I had replaced **very few** streams-oriented operations for "normal" loops in order to get a better performance on critical operations. My suggestion is: don't worry about "the best approach for performance reasons" unless you have proven (with close-to-real data) that it is a problem.

Comment: Make sense and thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should look forward to use `flatMap` while streaming over `names` and then performing `map` operation further correctly as:

```
List<String> result = names.stream() // for each name
        .flatMap(name -> versions.stream() // for each version
                .map(version -> name.concat(version))) // concat version to the name
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect all such names
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a bit tidier:

```
final List<String> result = names.stream()          // Stream the Names...
        .flatMap(name    -> versions.stream()       // ...together with Versions.
        .map    (version -> name.concat(version)))  // Combine Name+Version
        .collect(Collectors.toList());              // & collect in List.
```